# Install packages that rely on Tensorflow with 'Tensorflow-macos'

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1, arm64

I have managed to install tensorflow-macos on my Macbook with M1 chip

[image]

But whenever I try to install a package that requires tensorflow I get an error, stating that tensorflow is not/can not be installed.

[image]

How can I work around this issue? I assume tensorflow-macos is the replacement of tensorflow for Macs running arm64 chips but how can I actually make the packages know that it is?

Comment: Hi! Error suggests the package you trying to install might be restricted to 2.2 or 2.3 and not allowing 2.8. You can install that package using below command. pip install <packagename> tensorflow==2.2. Could you please share that package name.

Comment: @ user11530462 I think you are wrong. The version states ">=" and not exact version. I am having the same issue